# How to create a multi level dropdown with react with data in an array?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I have my data coming in like this:

```
[
  {
    type_1: 'team A',
    type_2: 'item1',
    type_3: 'task A'
  },
  {
    type_1: 'team A',
    type_2: 'item1',
    type_3: 'task B'
  },
  {
    type_1: 'team A',
    type_2: 'item1',
    type_3: 'task C'
  },
  {
    type_1: 'team B',
    type_2: 'item2',
    type_3: 'task D'
  },
  {
    type_1: 'team B',
    type_2: 'item2',
    type_3: 'task E'
  },
  {
    type_1: 'team B',
    type_2: 'item3',
    type_3: 'task A'
  }
]
```

I need to create 3 drop downs first one choses team > based on selection choose item > based on that choose task. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by the following way

```
render() {
    let data = [
        {
            type_1: 'team A',
            type_2: 'item1',
            type_3: 'task A'
        },
        {
            type_1: 'team A',
            type_2: 'item1',
            type_3: 'task B'
        },
        {
            type_1: 'team A',
            type_2: 'item1',
            type_3: 'task C'
        },
        {
            type_1: 'team B',
            type_2: 'item2',
            type_3: 'task D'
        },
        {
            type_1: 'team B',
            type_2: 'item2',
            type_3: 'task E'
        },
        {
            type_1: 'team B',
            type_2: 'item3',
            type_3: 'task A'
        }
    ]
    return (
        <>
            <select>
                {
                    data.map(item => {
                        return (
                            <option>{item.type_1}</option>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </select>
            <select>
                {
                    data.map(item => {
                        return (
                            <option>{item.type_2}</option>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </select>
            <select>
                {
                    data.map(item => {
                        return (
                            <option>{item.type_3}</option>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </select>
        </>
    )
}
```